# 'System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection' does not contain a definition for 'MapHttpRoute'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

In the RoutingConfig.cs I added the below code for handling the Handling HTTP 404 Error in ASP.NET Web API

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Error404",
            routeTemplate: "{*url}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "Handle404" }
        );
    }
}
```

It throws the below error like

> 'System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection' does not contain a definition for
>   'MapHttpRoute' and no extension method 'MapHttpRoute' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried to ass the namespace `System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection` but it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following

```
//Catch-All InValid (NotFound) Routes
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Error404",
    url: "{*url}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "Handle404" }
);
```

Make sure that this is the last route to be mapped as this is a catch-all route.

Comment: It throws error like `The best overload for 'MapRoute' does not have a parameter named 'routeTemplate' `

Comment: use `url:` not `routeTemplate`.

Comment: I edited my question with the Code from the RouteConfig.cs

Comment: Can the RouteCongig.cs have two routes.MapRoute

Comment: it can have any amount of map routes. that's what it's there for

Answer (score 0):

because `the following URI does not match, because it lacks the "api" segment.`

https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api

`RouteTemplate`s are configured for routing incoming requests.

Comment: I tried to follow the article https://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/handling-http-404-error-in-asp-net-web-api

Comment: the article has a lot of custom code. Did you try them all?

Comment: did you debug to where exactly your code goes wrong.